# MS Visual C++ 2010 Express - Breakpoints (red dots) not showing

Tags: breakpoints, visual-c++-2010-express

When setting breakpoints in MS Visual C++ Express 2010, a 'red dot' will be shown at the location of the breakpoint. 
Now all of a sudden this 'red dot' disappeared. The breakpoint is being set, but the location is not shown any more.
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: It might be on a line of code that has been optimized away, or is in some way or other not reachable?

Comment: have you been playing around with the project settings?

Answer (score 0):

If the red dots disappear on running this means that any compiled code corresponding to your source code is not going to be ran. There are many reasons, but in (I think) most likely order:

1) Are you trying to run a debug build? (On a release build the red dots will disappear)

2) Have you built the project?

3) Have you rebuilt the project from scratch?

4) Are you sure that the dll is actually loaded? (Not applicable to an exe target of course).

If none of these fixes it (and, in particular, if you've been fiddling with the project settings) then let me know; we'll need to delve deeper.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, unfortunately I do not understand what you are trying to say. The only thing I always do is rebuild solution, set a breakpoint, and start debugging. The only difference now is that my breakpoint are not vissible anymore.

Comment: Are you sure you're running the debug build?

Comment: To clarify, even if you just start up MS Visual C++ 2010 Express, you are normally able to set breakpoints, and a red dot/circle will appear when you set it. This is not happening anymore. So I normally do not have to debug before seeing te red dots/circles.

Comment: I'd be tempted to bet a bottle of Dom Perignon on the fact that you have a release build selected for 'debugging'.

Comment: Can you please tell me step by step what I should do instead? Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: I checked, but I really do not have a release build selected for debugging.. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Is it a dll or an exe target?

Comment: Ah. Now we can hardcode a break point using inline asasembly. Write `__asm int 3;` where you want a breakpoint to be. Your program *will* stop at that line, if you are really debugging the exe.

Comment: A popup shows: "K0055.exe has triggered a breakpoint". Two options: break or continue.

Comment: Choose break; and let me know what happens. Can you step through with the debugger now?

Comment: Yes, I can step through with debugger. That was always possible. Just the red dots/circles are not visible. So it is difficult to see where the breakpoints are located..